# Why I get a message of outdated packages minutes after I have updated?

Tags: 12.04, updates, indicator, taskbar

[image: Yellow alert icon on top panel]

I have getting a yellow exclamation mark in the top panel on 12.04. It tells me I have updates that are outdated when I just updated a few minutes ago. How do you correct the updates?

Comment: Click on the icon and have it to check again. Probably is not yet aware of the recent update.

Comment: When I complete the  updates it goes away, but sometime later it shows up again. That doesn't seem to fix the problem for long.

Comment: I think I solved the problem by removing the respository packages that the updates failed on. The icon vanished for now or is gone now.

Comment: Then the indicator just reflected the fact that, indeed, some packages were not updated. If you still are going to use the programs from those repositories, you will have to add the repositories again and update when it is possible to connect to them. In any case, I'm glad your problem is solved. Type your answer and accept it.

Comment: @MichaelScott Please, if your problem is gone, (as stated above) **create a new answer** and write all the procedures that you did.